# Как сохранить эффект hover при нахождении курсора на следующем уровне меню?

Tags: html

Добрый день!

Как сделать так, чтобы верхняя картинка в горизонтальном выплывающем меню менялась не только при наведении на неё, но и в тот момент, когда курсор находится на появившемся, после наведения на неё, подменю.

Формулировка вопроса не очень, я понимаю, поэтому приложу скриншот.)

http://s3.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2013/11/78db853ae9d2c6fd390b5744e1b99145.jpg

каждый < li> в меню сделан через

> < a href="x.html" class="x">

в css

> ```
> a.x {
> background: url(x);
> display: block; 
> width: 160px; 
> height: 72px;     }    
> a.x:hover {
> background-position: 0 -72px;     }
> ```

Благодарю!

Comment: Так оберните все в дополнительный тег. И сам компонент и его подменю. Ну и в зависимости от наведения на этот тег делайте все, что вам нужно. Не прокатит?

Comment: Идею понял, но что-то не доходит как реализовать. Вот у меня код того меню, что на скриншоте:

<li><a href="pb.html" class="ser1"></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="pb_watch.html" class="watch1"></a></li>
<li><a href="pb_download.html" class="download"></a></li>
<li><a href="pb_info.html" class="info"></a></li>
<li><a href="pb_other.html" class="other"></a></li>
</ul></li>

Если все это дело обернуть в ещё один <a></a>, то что в его стиле прописывать? Если бы можно было написать a.test:hover { a.ser1:hover { background x.png } }, тогда нет проблем, но ведь так нельзя :с

Какашками не кидаться, я новичок.

Answer (score 1):

Если такой html

```
<li><a href="pb.html" class="ser1"></a> <ul> <li><a href="pb_watch.html" class="watch1"></a></li> <li><a href="pb_download.html" class="download"></a></li> <li><a href="pb_info.html" class="info"></a></li> <li><a href="pb_other.html" class="other"></a></li> </ul></li>
```

такой css:

```
ul > li:hover  {
   border:10px solid red;
}

ul > li ul li:hover {
   border:none;
}
```